# Using VBA ADO on Excel, I am looking for an Update query to get an univocal, 1 to 1 match

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I have a table similar to the following (tab1):

```
ID Descr Related_ID
1  a     2
2  a     1
3  a     1
4  a     1
5  b     6
6  b     5
7  b     5
8  b     5
```

my query is something like:

```
Update [tab1] as T1 INNER JOIN [tab1] as t2
ON t1.[Descr] = t2.[Descr]
SET t1.[Related_ID] = t2.[ID]
WHERE t1.[ID] <> t1.[Related_ID]
```

the idea is to create couple/pair between the rows of the table to get for each line one on only one ID of another line.
What the query is actually doing is overwriting each time Related_ID, with the latter table2 ID.
Instead of just use any ID only once.
The result I would like is like:

```
ID Descr Related_ID
1  a     2
2  a     1
3  a     4
4  a     3
5  b     6
6  b     5
7  b     8
8  b     7
```

I would like to create a couple / pair of element where the related_id of one is the ID of the other and viceversa.

Could you help me please?

PS:

A. I am using vba adodb on excel not on access

B. I need to maintain a good degree of efficiency, if I would implement sub query such as `WHERE not [ID] IN (SELECT [ID] FROM [tab2] WHERE ...)`
the efficiency will be highly impacted (from few seconds to half an hour) as the table has hundreds of rows

thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like something you could easiiy do with SQL: you need a way to pick out a single record from t2 to use to update each t1 record, and all you're doing is excluding the exact match.  You'd need some way to identify the "next/previous" record, and that's not really a thing in a DB table...

Comment: I know is not common, I tried to look to lot of material online, but I thought someone can give me some creative solution, like, if I set SET t1.[Related_ID] = t1.[Related_ID] & t2.[ID]   I'll get the list of all the possible corresponding ID, then with another inner join or something that I do not know remove all the repetitive one. keeping only one!